# Compiling RTMidi in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, coremidi

I'm having issues trying to compile RTMidi on Xcode 4 in a C++ project.

The information for doing this is at: http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/index.html#compiling

The problem is that I don't really know how to set those compiling flags on Xcode. When I build, everything runs perfect but I always get 0 Midi inputs and Outputs but I do have many devices connected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just aded the precompiler macro **MACOSX_CORE** and it worked like a charm! I did it in the wrong place before

Comment: @acrogenesis The correct place is to add the precompiler macro:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928622/add-preprocessor-macro-to-a-target-in-xcode-6 That should give you an idea.