# upgrading libmosquitto from 1.1.3 to 1.4.8 in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, mosquitto, libmosquitto

I am working on a project where I am using libmosquitto 1.1.3. It is working fine with WITH_TLS flags for ssl.

Now I have to upgrade the library to latest version which is 1.4.8.
I was unable to download new  library but it does not have WITH_TLS flag in it. 
When I copied this Preprocessor to my file it gave error openssl/ssl.h file not found.

Any on using this library in iOS , Please suggest something.

Comment: not familiar with this at all, but you said suggest something! Have you tried adding the WITH_TLS flag to the preprocessor macros for the Xcode project (assuming you have an Xcode project)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928622/add-preprocessor-macro-to-a-target-in-xcode-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, After a lot of research, I came to know that the difference between Two library is the Version 1.1.3 has WITH_TLS flag setting only in one file/place. But Version 1.4.8 of Mosquito has some new file related to TLS and WITH_TLS has to be set there too.

After setting this flag at two places I am successfully abel to compile..

:)