# Is it possible to have Fabric and AppStore builds at the same time?

Tags: ios, app-store, twitter-fabric

I have an app for iPhone and always sending a testing builds to client. At the same time I have an App Store version of this app. Client wants to have beta and stable app version on device at the same time. Is it possible to do without creating a new app with another bundle id?

Answer (score 0):

You can only have on app on your device with the same BundleID.
If you want both the appstore version and a test version you will need to create a new BundleID for this test version.

Comment: It's really bad :( coz I have a APNS enabled on my remote server connected with my bundle id :(

Comment: Sorry, but this is your only option. You might want your backend to accept some kind of labeled version so you can have multiple APNS configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you could do this using separate IDs for the debug and built app and using multiple schemes to share the code base between them.

Check out this article that will help
http://nilsou.com/blog/2013/07/29/how-to-have-two-versions-of-the-same-app-on-your-device/

--Edit--

Just noticed you specifically don't want different bundles due to Push Notifications. We got around this by letting our back end services know which app we were using, and targeting the different services based on which app they use. You can do this by defining preprocessor macros like this: [Add preprocessor macro to a target in xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928622/add-preprocessor-macro-to-a-target-in-xcode-6)

... then reference them just before you call your back end service to register your device like this...

```
#ifdef ENTERPRISE
    env = GLOBAL_PushNotificationEnvironmentEnt;
#endif
#ifdef DEBUG
    // In debug mode, the environment should be set to Development
    env = GLOBAL_PushNotificationEnvironmentDev;
#endif

    if (notificationsOnBool) {
        [service RegisterPushNotificationTarget:self
                               TargetType:GLOBAL_PushNotificationTargetType
                                    TargetToken:deviceID
                                     DeviceName:[UIDevice currentDevice].name
                                EnvironmentType:env];
    }
```

... then in your back end code you do something like this (psuedo-code)

```
if (device.env == Fabric) {
    sendNotification(fabricService);
} else {
    sendNotification(prodService);
}
```